# 4060BE Starts With Output High

Tags: integrated-circuit, counter, ripple

Is a 4060B IC meant to start with Logic 1 on outputs, or does it start counting from 0? Surely as its a binary counter, its meant to start with all outputs on logic 0, and count up using binary?

My circuit with a 4060BE IC has nothing else but a resistor and a capacitor, and it appears to start with all logic 0. How would I start counting on Logic 0, would I just have to use an inverter to flip the input?

Comment: Show me me your Vcc on power up and your schematic and layout and I will tell you why it happens to you and how to prevent it with POR or other methods. Normal practice to to see initial conditions on caps and see how that affects output or see if Vcc has noise or ***always use a Power on Reset RC filter.** to mitigate metastable power up conditions

Comment: The 4060 has a RESET input (pin 12), you should always reset the chip at power-on (POR) otherwise there is no guarantee in which state the outputs will start. Here's an example of resetting the chip with a resistor and a capacitor at power-on: https://dmohankumar.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/cd-4060-timer-circuit.gif (the R and C connected to pin 12 obviously).

Comment: Thanks, I will check. I do recall having Pin 12 connected straight to ground, however I guess I must use a capacitor and resistor in series.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the rules in the datasheet. and your power up Vcc rise time (10% to 90%) is less than than T2= R2C2, then  the initial condition is $0.

**Check this assumption and increase R2C2 while satisfying below datasheet requirements to fix your problem.**

The capacitor to ground C2 serves two purposes; one for power up reset and the other for steady state 50% control of the RC oscillator duty cycle.

- Either input =0 to NAND forces rising edge clock=0
- acts as a low pass filter of the clock to guarantee a 50% duty cycle

  - this is a negative feedback loop, DC gain =1 relative to internal gate thresholds for Nch and Pc
- gain >= 10x per FET CMOS stage thus astable clock conditions are met
  [image]

In summary, if you ignore MR=0 the forcing functions that control the counter clock input are the input Cap C2 which is inverted on the 1st CMOS gate and follows the supply cap on Vcc.  Both will rise with Vcc but C2 will settle to Vcc/2 upon which the 1st CMOS stage becomes a linear amplifier and it's output inverts from Hi to Low as Vcc is rising and thus the 2nd CMOS inverting gate gets it's 1st rising edge as the counter clk input. Then the next clock edge is determined by R1C1 time constant so R2C2 determines the latency needed to let power up stabilize.

- There "may" be a glitch or metastable condition where a few xx nanosecond glitch equal to the Vgs threshold , which the older CD4060 family IC's ignored due to bandwidth limits but perhaps the 74ACT4060 responds from some suppliers or your supply has excessive ripple during power up and you learn to understand

> that ALL LOGIC have ANALOG characteristics.

**This compatibility flaw is when the designer learns to follow standard practice of a separate discrete Power On Reset controlled starting condition for all bistable logic to prevent POR race conditions or other undesirable characteristics.**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to assure that your logic has a known condition at power up is to use a properly designed reset circuit that combines both a voltage reference + comparator and a timed output pulse. These are generically known as supervisory chips when supplied in monolithic form. Ideally they will work down to a voltage where your logic is guaranteed **not** to work, in order to prevent any mischief during low voltage conditions. All RC or RC+diode circuits are not guaranteed to work if the supply is briefly interrupted or comes up too slowly.

Cheaping out on the reset circuit is a MAJOR cause of malfunctions in consumer goods. [Here](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1812.pdf) is a typical example of a chip that might be suitable for a 5V supply (not a recommendation of this particular Maxim part). If your supply is 5V you just wire the active high RST output to the RESET input of your counter and you're done (pick the appropriate threshold voltage).

[image]

The only thing you need to do to make this absolutely bulletproof is to ensure that the supply cannot dip for an extremely short time such that the 130ms pulse would not be triggered but the counter would be corrupted. A sufficiently large bypass capacitor, which you should have anyway, will prevent that in almost all situations.